# Can't access elements appended by script in headless Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-headless

I'm accessing a webpage via headless chrome that *should* be running a script to append a few elements to the DOM. However, I can't figure out a way to get ahold of these elements

Trying to access them via DOM.querySelector within my Page.loadEventFired callback gives me nothing. I thought maybe this was because the script to append them hadn't finished executing by the time the querySelector was run, so I tried attaching a handler to the DOM.childNodeInserted event (both in the context of Page.loadEventFired and before navigating to the page) as follows:

`DOM.childNodeInserted((params) => {
    console.log("we have a child!!");
  });`

But the event never fires. My next approach was the DOM.setChildNodes event combined with DOM.requestChildNodes on the container elements for the inserted elements. I execute DOM.requestChildNodes within Page.loadEventFired. This event fires successfully, but reports no child nodes.

At this point, I'm confused as to whether the script is even running. Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: I don't think you have access to events caused by other scripts. Just a guess though. Maybe you should try a setTimeout for something longer than it would take the other script to run, then look for the elements. Also, try it in a headed chrome, see if something is getting added.

Comment: Just tried the setTimeout thing to no avail. And the elements are definitely getting as expected in regular Chrome.

Comment: Does your code work in regular Chrome?